# How do I change the post title's link on the posts page?

Tags: posts, plugin-development, filters

I created a plugin that if the post is in a certain category, it will change the content to display a login message if the user is not logged in. How can I change the post title's link from my plugin?

Note: My code is at https://github.com/NerdOfLinux/MemberOnly/

If you know the plugin `Ultimate Member`, I want something similar to their custom post settings to only allow logged in users to access the post, and redirect users who are not logged in to the login page.

Comment: I don't understand... "How can I change the URL displayed on the posts page(the title with a link to the post) from the plugin?" Can you reformulate please?

Comment: The title of the post that when you click it, it takes you to the permalink

Comment: Ok, you want to replace the title's link, but then, by what do you want to replace it? Also, I'm not sure to understand when do you want to change it, under which conditions, etc... From all this could depend the solution.

Comment: How can I change it from a plugin. I'll put it in the right place in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use  the [`post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'wpse_change_post_link', 99, 3 );

function wpse_change_post_link( $url, $post, $leavename = false ) {
    // Can't fill these conditions since you didn't specify them...
    if ( 'my_post_type' === $post->post_type ) {
        $url = ''; // Your new URL...
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. My plugin is https://github.com/NerdOfLinux/MemberOnly/

Comment: @NerdOfLinux I just checked a little of your code on GitHub... You put my code which include a function declaration in another function declaration... Of course it doesn't work... Put my whole code in global scope.

Comment: How can I apply that to certain posts and not all?

Comment: @NerdOfLinux see the updated answer.